# Не работает авторизация на php

Tags: php

У меня не получается сделать авторизацию на сайте!
Регистрирует у меня все хорошо, а вот войти на сайт не хочет!
Я пользуюсь функцией `md5()` и у меня бд все шифрует отлично, но как сделать что бы оно входило тоже через эту функцию? Так же оно не входит и без этой функции, пожалуйста помогите!!!

Я уже не знаю что делать.

---

Вот код авторизации:

```
<?php 
require("include/connect.php");
if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
    header("Location: main.php"); // вывод "Session is set"; // в целях проверки
}

if(isset($_POST['button-login'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password_1'])) {
        $login = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login']);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password_1']);
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$login."' AND password='".$password."'");
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows!=0){
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $dbusername=$row['login'];
                $dbpassword=$row['password_1'];
            }
            if($login == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword){
                // старое место расположения
                //  session_start();
                $_SESSION['login']=$login;
                $_SESSION['user_id']=$login;
                header("Location: main.php");
            }
        } else {
            echo  "Invalid username or password!"; // $message = "Invalid username or password!";
        }
    } else {
        $message = "All fields are required!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы был нормальный вход на сайт!!!!

Comment: Нормальный вход будет после того, как вы напишете нормальный код. В котором хотя бы отступы будут нормальные. Вы что не можете `var_dump` каждую переменную на каждой строчке и узнать что не так?

Comment: а что у вас в `connect.php`?

Comment: Я конечно не разбираюсь в php, но `Так же оно не входит и без этой функции`, естественно не будет, пароль в БД уже лежит зашифрованный.

Comment: Авторизация - это проверка привилегий при доступе к ресурсу. То, что в вопросе называется аутентификация.

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял, вы сравнивает хэш с обычными паролем. Попробуйте так.

```
if($login == $dbusername && md5($password) == $dbpassword)
```